# wait_for with ansible not working

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am using ansible's git module (using ansible 2.1) to pull a repo and then change into the downloaded repo using the shell module (I can try the command if shell does not work).  I have a role with two include.yml files (one that pulls from git and the second that uses the shell command) - both inside the tasks directory of the role.  The git clone works but even the shell command right after that does not (it cannot seem to detect that the directory got created - even though I can go to that directory using another shell).  I tried using the wait_for (but it never returns).  I am using my local user ID to do all the tasks and the git repo gets created with my ID.  Any thoughts on how to resolve this:

**shell.yml**

```
---
- wait_for: path=/tmp/my-repos/my-proj
- shell: cd /tmp/my-repos/my-proj
```

**main.yml**

```
---
- include: git.yml
- include: shell.yml
```

**git.yml**

```
---
- name: fetching my repo
  local_action: git repo={{ my_repo_url }} 
                    dest={{ my_proj_path }}  
                    accept_hostkey=yes
                    depth=10
                    version={{ my_project_version }}
```

Comment: issue was not using local_action before the shell command - the command was being run on the remote machine, not the controller machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue was not using local_action before the shell command - the command was being run on the remote machine, not the controller machine

```
---
- local_action: shell cd /tmp/my-repos/my-proj
```

Comment: there is a time limit before you can accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

This is because git module clone locally a repo and 'shell' and 'wait_for' modules are performed on another host (according your inventory file)

If your playbook must be played fully on localhost, you can:

1) remove 'local_action' in **git.yml**:

`---
- name: fetching my repo
  git repo={{ my_repo_url }}
    dest={{ my_proj_path }}
    accept_hostkey=yes
    depth=10
    version={{ my_project_version }}`

2) call your playbook with 'local' connector plugin:

`ansible-playbook -i "localhost," -c local main.yml`

The advantage: you can use this playbook on a remote host if you want.

I don't understand why you need to use module 'wait_for', 'git' module ensures repository is cloned before next task.

Comment: thanks - I posted my answer - I ran the shell command using local_action (it was running on the remote host even thought the git clone/repo was on the controller machine).  it was an oversight on my end - appreciate your feedback